# Pre-Defined themes for AJAX Control Toolkit controls

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Are there any custom built themes available on the web for controls in AJAX Control toolkit ?

Else, I will need to create styles/themes on my own which can be tedious and time-consuming for a developer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Walkthrough/OtherNeatStuff.aspx

'Theming is now enabled on all controls extending from ExtenderControlBase. You can create a theme in the web application and add .skin files to it. If you do not provide an ID for the skin it becomes the default skin for all controls on pages using that theme.'

More about skins can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx

I don't think there are many free themes or skins about but a few are available for purchase as part of the developer controls from companies like Telerik, RAD, devexpress etc

Comment: I was looking for pre-built themes like Green theme or Blue Theme or Orange theme, instead of developing the themes myself. The links you gave will not provide themes but will explain how to build themes.